# Extract all String values from a list of map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am receiving a rest response in following format.

```
{
    "query_result": {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "Results Found",
        "results": [
            {
                "key": "123"
            },
            {
                "key": "465"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From this response, I want to create a list of String from the keys.
Thus looking to get a list outcome as follows:

```
["123", "456"]
```

Trying to produce the output as follows but stuck at the map step in following code block.

```
public Optional<List<String>> get(HttpEntity<Request> request){
    ResponseEntity<Response> response = getResponse(request); // this response holds above json data 

    return Optional.ofNullable(response)
            .map(ResponseEntity::getBody)
            .map(Response::getQueryResult)
            .map(QueryResult::getResults)
            .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
            .map(results -> results.) // Stuck here. results here is the list of results shown in above json. 
}
```

I am not able to pull out all the key's values from here.
I end up having to indicate index as follows which is not going to work since I want all keys.

```
.map(results -> results.get(0))
```

Tried considering using iterator but that would again only end up capturing the first key only.

```
.filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
.map(List::iterator)
.map(Iterator::next)
.map(result -> result.getKey())
```

Could I please get some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
.map(QueryResult::getResults)
.filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
.map(results -> results.stream().map(Key::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Assumed that each key object is mapped correctly to a class called `Key` which looks like this:

```java
class Key {
    String key;

    String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

you want on your `Optional` chain to transform its internal List of `Key`s to a List of `String`s. So the final step just takes care of that part.

###### Note

1. Your method returns an Optional list. Generally it's better on semantics if you return an empty list instead of `null`, but that's up to the implementation.
2. If it's getting hard to understand the lambdas, move their logic to methods. For instance the above chain can become:

```java
List<String> collectKeys(List<Key> keys) {
    return keys.stream().map(Key::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())
}

// and then:
.map(QueryResult::getResults)
.filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
.map(this::collectKeys);
```